# share video on android 4.4

Tags: android, share, android-4.4-kitkat

i want to share video with whats app.on android 4.4 but my code not work and give me exception but it work on android 4.2.

my code is:

```
Intent var4 = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
                        var4.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", "choice pic");
                        var4.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", "text");
                        var4.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM",
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
                        var4.setType("video/*");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(var4, "select whatsapp to share"));
```

i haven't device with android 4.4 but i test my app on https://www.manymo.com so i can't get logcat.

Comment: Have you tried [the Manymo Command Line Tool](https://www.manymo.com/pages/documentation/manymo-command-line-tool) to make their emulator appear as a local emulator? I would hope that this makes LogCat available, at least via the **`adb logcat`** command.

Comment: yes but it not shown in emulator list.by the way my problem is about sharing in kitkat(4.4 android)